# Function only works once python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

i use the tkinter as a class with function, bur when i run one function that leads to another function, that again ends with running the first funktion again, but then the original function does not work. please help

```
def idle(self):
    self.next.destroy()
    self.info.destroy()

    self.prompt.configure(text=city_line + ", What do you want to do?")

    self.backpack = tk.Button(self, text="Backpack", command=self.backpack)
    self.shop = tk.Button(self, text="Shop")
    self.wander = tk.Button(self, text="Wander", command=self.wander)
    self.travel = tk.Button(self, text="Travel", command=self.travel)

    self.backpack.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
    self.shop.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
    self.wander.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
    self.travel.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)

def backpack(self):
    self.backpack.destroy()
    self.shop.destroy()
    self.wander.destroy()
    self.travel.destroy()
    self.output.destroy()
    self.info = tk.Message(self, width=150, text=backpacke + ". Gold: " + str(gold))
    self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")

    self.next = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=self.idle)
    self.info.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=8)
    self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
    self.next.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: Please post the complete class and how you call the class methods.

Answer (score 2):

When your class is created, you have a method named `backpack`. Inside the class, `self.backpack` refers to this method. When this method is called it does `self.backpack = tk.Button(...)` which effectively destroys the method and replaces it with the widget. The next time you try to call `self.backpack` you are calling the widget rather than your method.

You need to pick a different name for either the method or the variable that holds the widget.